# restrict the user to create only new Opportunity during conversion

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

During Lead Conversion, user can select existing Opportunity in Lightning.
But I want to restrict the user to create only new Opportunity during conversion.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It i not possible according to this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra8AAC